# Alternatives to Fuller’s (2009) Sampling Statistics

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, sampling, sampling-theory

I’m taking a self-study course in sampling statistics this semester and my professor chose Fuller’s (2009) Sampling Statistics for both the content and the homework questions.

However, I am really really struggling to understand the content under Fuller’s teaching method. There are many, many steps in Fuller’s work that are assumed to be understood; sadly, this causes me to spend 12+ hours per week trying to comprehend the background knowledge and failing. I really appreciate Fuller’s expertise but I would really appreciate a book that teaches topics a little more, as I want to be able to complete a homework question sometime soon.

Do you all have any recommendations for a rigorous sampling statistics textbook that generally does a good job of breaking down theorems? Since it is a self study course I would like to use these recommendations to propose a different text to my professor.

Comment: Try "Theoretical Statistics" by Keener. Ive only read a little from this one though. Another one is "Statistical Inference" by Casella and Berger, which has its problems (not fully rigorous).

Comment: @Mason Thank you, will check it out. Am tired of feeling so defeated :/